# TabHost наложение видов

Tags: java, android

В главном активити строю TabHost с 4-мя табами. Табы строятся без проблем, все работает. Переход осуществляется по разным активити. Код:

```
tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
TabHost.TabSpec Services2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Services2");
TabHost.TabSpec tabServices = tabHost.newTabSpec("Services");
tabServices.setIndicator("Services");
tabServices.setContent(new Intent(this, ServicesActivity.class));
tabEvakautor.setIndicator("Services2");
Services2.setContent(new Intent(this, ServicesActivity.class));
tabHost.addTab(tabServices);
tabHost.addTab(tabServices2); 
... и т.д.

Main.xml
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
tools:context="com.example.ivanvovk.MainActivity"
>
<TabWidget
    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/news_selector">
</TabWidget>
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

</FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Проблема заключается в том, что в активити Services(активити состоит из текстовых полей, кода много, если нужно приведу) я получаю наложение видов. Сам табвиджет не виден в этом активити программно(тут я имею в виду разметку xml), но виден как отображение из главного активити(собственно сам tabServices). На разных устройствах ширина tabcontent'a разная, поэтому не логично делать ее статичной. Как сообщить автивити, что внизу экрана располагается вид из TabWidget, чтобы она туда не "залезала"? Перечитал кучу материала, гуглить устал, не могу найти решения, подскажите варианты куда копать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить в Ваш frameLayout такой атрибут

```
android:layout_above="@android:id/tabs"
```

Comment: Гениально! Благодарю за помощь